# Batch Aggregate Raster using Python

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, batch

I am trying to write a python script to batch Aggregate a bunch of different rasters. I get a Parsing Error Syntax error for line 11.

```
# Batch Aggregate raster tool
import arcpy
from arcpy import env  
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r"C:\rasters"
out_workspace = r"C:\rasters\agg"

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in rasters
    outAggreg = Aggregate(raster, 10, "MEAN")
    outAggreg.save(out_workspace, raster + "_agg")
```

Comment: You are missing a colon after `rasters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following changes:

```
# Batch Aggregate raster tool
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env  
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r"C:\rasters"
out_workspace = r"C:\rasters\agg"


rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in rasters:
    outAggreg = Aggregate(raster, 10, "MEAN")
    outAggreg.save(os.path.join(out_workspace, raster + "_agg.tif"))
```

Comment: It ran, but this time I get an error:
RuntimeError: ERROR 010093: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported.  The input raster is an ECW and aggregate can't output that - it can output TIFFs though.

Comment: Try adding the .tif extension to the output path.

Comment: Bingo.  
    out_workspace, raster + "_agg.tif"
Thanks for the help!